# Get variable name from InArgument

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

I have a custom activity where the user selects a variable from a drop down list in a rehosted designer environment. My problem is I want to get variable's name along with its value. 

 Let's say my custom activity has  "InArgument MyVar{ get; set; }". 
I'm currently getting the variable's name by parsing "((Microsoft.VisualBasic.Activities.VisualBasicValue)MyVar.Expression).ExpressionText". Is there any better way?

Answer (score 0):

You can't surelly know the true value of an argument until the runtime.

But, you can take it's default value, using those extension methods:

```
    public static T GetImediateValueOrDefault<T>(Activity<T> activity, ModelItem modelItem)
    {
        if (activity == null)
            return default(T);

        var exprAsLiteral = activity as Literal<T>;
        if (exprAsLiteral != null)
            return exprAsLiteral.Value;

        var exprAsVbValue = activity as Microsoft.VisualBasic.Activities.VisualBasicValue<string>;
        if (exprAsVbValue != null)
            return modelItem.GetDefaultValueOfScopedVariable<T>(exprAsVbValue.ExpressionText);

        return default(T);
    }

    public static T GetDefaultValueOfScopedVariable<T>(this ModelItem modelItem, string variableName)
    {
        IEnumerable<ModelItem> scopedVariables = modelItem.GetScopedVariables();
        ModelItem variableModelItem = scopedVariables.FirstOrDefault(v => Equals(variableName, v.Properties["Name"].ComputedValue));
        if (variableModelItem == null)
            throw new KeyNotFoundException();

        Variable<T> variable = variableModelItem.GetCurrentValue() as Variable<T>;
        if (variable == null)
            return default(T);

        return GetImediateValueOrDefault(variable.Default, modelItem);
    }
```

*Not guaranteed, use with caution*

Comment: You see, in the runtime when the variable is passed to an InArgument I want to get the name of the variable that is passed.

Comment: @Arvand You do not wan't the value at design-time, you do want it at run-time - is that correct?

Just for clarification, why do you want the variable name at run-time?

Comment: because the variables are created based on a business logic, so when the designer is opened the variables are created automatically in xaml file and the business has a sense about the variables, so in runtime i pass a Dictionary of <string,objects> from my custom activity to the other methods.